# How to fix 'warning #1173-D: attribute "deprecated" ignored?'

Tags: gcc, omap

Some common utility functions need to be deprecated like this:

```
__attribute__((deprecated)) void TestDeprecatedMethod(int a, float b);
```

This works as expected on the ARM side of the OMAP like this:

```
warning: 'void CTest::TestDeprecatedMethod(int, float)' is deprecated
```

but it fails on the DSP side like this

```
warning #1173-D: attribute "deprecated" ignored
```

using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 and ti-dvsdk_omapl138-evm_4_02_00_06/c6000_7.4.7. What needs to be changed on the DSP build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to TI

> C6000 compiler versions 7.4.x do not support the GCC attribute
>   deprecated.